# Windows Workflow: Persistence and Polling

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I'm currently learning the WF framework, so bear with me; mostly I'm looking for *where* to start looking, not necessarily a direct answer. I just can't seem to figure out how to begin researching what I'd like in The Google.

Let's say I have a simple one-step workflow (much more complicated than that, but for simplicity's sake). This workflow needs to watch a certain record in the database to see when it changes. I don't have the capability to "push" via a trigger from the database when the row changes, so I need to poll for it every so often.

This workflow needs to be persisted to the database to be durable against restarts and whatnot as this is a long-running workflow. I'm trying to figure out the best way to get it to check every 3 minutes or so and also persist to the database. Do the persistence capabilities of the framework allow for that? It seems to be time-based. And since the workflow won't be reawakened by an external event, how does it reload from the database and check the same step it did previously again? Does it attempt the last unfulfilled activity automatically upon reloading?

Do "while" activities with a delay attached to it work at all, or can it be handled solely through the persistence services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "handled soley through persistence services"? Persistence refers only to the storing of an idle workflow.

You could have a Delay and a Code activity in a Sequence in a While loop.  When in the Delay the workflow will go idle and may be persisted if necessary.  However depending on how much state is needed when persisting the workflow and/or how many such workflows you would have running at any one time may mean that a leaner approach is necessary.

A leaner approach would be to externalise the DB watching and have some "DB watching" workflow service raise an event when the desired change has occured.  This service would be added to Workflow runtime.

To that end you need a service contract which is defined by an Inteface with the [ExternalDataExchange] attribute.  This interface in turn defines an event that the service will raise when the desired DB change is detected.  It also defines a method that a Workflow can call to specify what what change this service should be looking for.  The method should accept an instance GUID so that the requesting instance can be found when the DB change is detected.

In the workflow you use a CallExternalMethodActivity to call this services method.  You then flow to a HandleExternalEventActivity which listen for the event.  At this point the workflow will go idle and can be persisted.  It will remain there until the service raises the event.

Comment: I really like that approach. It clears up some of the architectural questions I have around this framework. Thanks!